# Localhost is too Slow on ampps 3.8

Tags: php, mysql, performance, codeigniter-3, ampps

I am using Ampps 3.8 for localserver and it was working fine at my office. It was nice and i could easily change php versions for test purposes.

But when i tried to access localhost or change php versions from my home network, it takes lots of time and many of my assets like css, images etc are not loading. I am doing a project in Codeigniter and php 7.

details of my configuration are as follows:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://192.168.43.122/projects/neewer';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';

//db config
$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'   => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'neewer',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt' => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Configs seems to be correct. Why are you using '192.168.43.122' instead of localhost? most porobably that will be the issue as u said ur system is working fine at your office and not at your home.

maybe that ip address will be of your office network. Try changing it to your home networks ip address or just to localhost like below code and try again.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://192.168.43.122/projects/neewer';
```

to

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/projects/neewer';
```

Hopefully this will do the trick if the issue is differences in IP Addresses. let us know if that doesnt help and if you need any help further.

Comment: Thnks for your response @Rishad. Let me check that and will let you know at the earliest.

Comment: happy to know it helped :)